# PHP Load more results in the order as retrieved from the url using $_GET

Tags: php

I am trying to get all the items that are loaded (after clicking load more) to be sorted out according to the filter settings that were submitted before hand.
I have all the settings being displayed on the url as the form is submitted with GET

For some reason, I cannot retrieve the settings from the url using GET after the form is submitted and load more is clicked.. any idea why?

This query sorts out all the results:

```
<div class="main_page">
    <?php

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ".$search_query." ".$lowest_price." ".$highest_price." ".$ad_order." ".$limit."");

    if($res && mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $date = $row['date']; 
        }
        echo '<div class="ad_display" id="'.$date.'">blabla</div>';
    }
```

In the loadmore.php, there is the exact same div but it is sorted out like so:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `date` < '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

and of course the load more button script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".load_more").click(function (){
        $('.load_more').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        $.ajax({
            url: "loadmore.php?id=" + $(".ad_display:last").attr("id"),
            success: function(html){
            if(html){
                $(".main_page").append(html);
                $('.load_more').html('Load More');
            }else{
                $('.load_more').replaceWith('No more posts');
            }
        }
    });
    });
});
</script>

<button class="load_more">Load More</button>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE:

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $searchq = $_GET['search'];
    $searchq = sanitize(preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq));
    $search_query = "AND (title LIKE '%".$searchq."%' OR description LIKE '%".$searchq."%')";
}
```

Comment: Where is `$search_query` etc. defined?

Comment: What form? And in `loadmore.php`, the ordering seems to be static, so why to you expect the results to be ordered by anything else then `date` as you specified there?

Comment: updated the code above with the search_query. And @CBroe yes I know but I tried simply echo $_GET['search_query'] and it will tell me undefined variable

Comment: Your code has SQL Injection vulnerabilities. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: The updated code is what goes into $res once the form is submitted.. sorry there is a lot of code so it's hard not to miss parts here and there and I try not to make a giant page of code when I am asking here

Comment: Well your `$search_query` variable does only get set when there is a GET parameter named `search`, I assume – but you are not passing any such parameter in your AJAX request, so …

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `date` < '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

In the line above from `loadmore.php` you have one single, static ordering statement: `ORDER BY date DESC`.

The code you provided does not make it clear, but I presume `$ad_order` contains the ordering you're using on the main page and the ordering you'd *like* to use within `loadmore.php`. However this is computed from the query string, so you need to pass the values into `loadmore.php` and duplicate the code in there. For example, if your main page has this:

```
// main-page.php?order1=X&order2=Y

$ad_order = "Some kind of computation with the values from the query string";
```

Then you also need to have that code inside `loadmore.php`, and you need to modify your two scripts, like this...

```
// loadmore.php

$ad_order = "The same computation with values from the query string";

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `date` < '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."' " . $ad_order . " LIMIT 10")
```

...and this...

```
// Loading function in JavaScript

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".load_more").click(function (){
            $('.load_more').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadmore.php?order1=<?=$_GET['order1'];?>&order2=<?=$_GET['order2'];?>&id=" + $(".ad_display:last").attr("id"),
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is a **GENERIC** example of what the solution should be - there's not enough detail in your question for me to be exact, so you'll need to change variable names and the `$ad_order` code to make it work with your script.

Also, as Second Rikudo said above, your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection. You should have a read of the article that was linked to.

Comment: for the jquery code, that will only work if the user chose filters but if not then there are not variables after index.php to pass into $_GET. I tried doing what you said before with the "The same computation with values ..." to be passed into the loadmore.php page using the $_GET function but it didn't work for some reason. As far as what $ad_order is, it is just if(isset($_GET['ad_order']) && $_GET['ad_order'] === "1"){$ad_order = "ORDER BY `date` DESC";... and so on, just different combinations of displaying the posts